# Scalability of Django Tenant Schema

Tags: django, postgresql, schema, multi-tenant

I have made a basic ERP webapp using django-tenant schema. Now, my problem is every time a new user signs up, its a downtime (because of migration, which helps in creating new schema for each user). So, this is surely not scalable. I'm using psotgresql as my database, apache and DO.

Is there a possible answer to this woe?

The issue I'm facing is I'm planning on using this ERP system for multiple SMEs. Now, each of these SMEs deploy 10-15 employees, all of whom would have an account, created by the employer with required permission). Now, is that possible without schema? Add to that the trouble of scanning ultra large table every time.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an application in django/postgres which was multi-tenant. The technique I used was to:

1) have each tenant login in with unique credentials.
2) each tenant has a tenant_id
3) every table has a tenant_id
4) create views in postgres using the tenant_id for each table.  so, when a tenant selects from a table, they see all rows in that table that match their tenant_id

This worked pretty well for me.  You do have added overhead.  You have to related a tenant_id to a session.  You will need to add a schema to your database to create the views for each table you want the tenant to have access to.

This has the added benefit where tables that aren't tenant specific and are read only can be shared between tenants.

-g

Comment: Well, so if I'm not wrong Greg, what u did was multi-tenant with same schema. This is what I thought initially. But this doesn't augers well with my use case. That's where the problem lies.U c, in my case, the complexity is added with each tenant being able to create multiple user. For eg, if someone uses my ERP, he/she needs to create sub users for different modules of the ERP, like one for Accounts, one for SCM, etc.. So, it adds complexity if schema is not used.

Comment: i had the same issue.  also, my users could belong to different tenants.  it does work.  the part i think your are missing is that even though they share the same schema, they are separated as if they are different schemas.  you create the separation with the login. you remember the tenant_id and your application accesses the db via views, which select everything with the correct tenant_id.  Maybe it isn't appropriate for you, just thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: Thanks a lot Greg!! Surely I'll have to think in your lines to some extent as well. I'm also thinking about doing migrate-schemas for new tenants only. Like migration for one schema only (the way migrate-schema --public migrates public schema only). Let me dig up django & d-t-s source code and keep my fingers crossed